# Javascript reference a function with a string (in a module)

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a JS file loaded into the head as a module:

```
<script type="module" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

In the main.js file I have a number of function that need to be called dynamically, depending on what instance of a button is clicked.

The normal solution would be to use `window["my_func"]` but this doesn't work in a module context.

I can get around this by assigning each function to the window i.e `window.my_func = my_func;` but is there something I'm missing here? Is there something similar to `window["my_func"]` that works in the module scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the module namespace object, then use it as you've shown. So instead of including `/js/main.js` directly in a `script` tag, have another module in the `script` tag that does the import and calls the functions as needed:

```
import * as fns from "/js/main.js";

fns["my_func"]();
```

For example, suppose you had `functions.js`:

```
function show(msg) {
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.textContent = msg;
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(p);
}
export function one() {
    show("Function one called");
}
export function two() {
    show("Function two called");
}
```

and `main.js`:

```
import * as fns from "./functions.js";

const timer = setInterval(() => {
    const fn = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "one" : "two";
    fns[fn]();
}, 800);
setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(timer);
}, 10000);
```

And you loaded `main.js`:

```html
<script type="module" src="./main.js">
```

That would call either `one` or `two` from `functions.js` once every 800ms until 10 seconds had passed. [Example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-zajs8e?file=index.html,functions.js,main.js,styles.css) (since Stack Snippets don't support multiple files).

Comment: "_since Stack Snippets don't support multiple files_": @T.J.Crowder FWIW, you can load ES modules from text in snippets ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75684351/438273))

Comment: @jsejcksn - True, but you can't `import` from them (directly), so I figured plain code blocks were sufficient (and the link for those for whom it isn't blocked). :-)